# Print what is the lowest number without lists, tuples and dictionaries

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, if-statement, tuples

I can use for loops, while and if statements. I'm struggling on how I can do that. I tried using this but is has a tuple. Canada_tax, Norway_tax, USA_tax and Denmark_tax have a value and the calculations are above this code.

```
min_tax = (canada, norway_tax, USA_tax, denmark_tax)
     min = min_tax[0]
     for i in min_tax:
        if i < min:
            min = i
     print(f'Lowest tax: {min}')
     
     if min == canada :
        print('Canada')

     if min == denmark_tax :
        print('Denmark')

     if min == norway_tax :
        print('Norway')

     if min == USA_tax :
        print('USA')
     print()
```

What I want to happen is this:

Income: 1000000
Lowest tax: 150000.0
USA
Income: 6000
Lowest tax: 1500.0
Denmark Norway USA
Income: -1

When the countries have the same lowest tax it should print them out in alphabetic row.

Comment: The restrictions are weirdly phrased - I don't see why you would use a for or while loop here, for instance, without having a collection to iterate over. That said, it sounds like your teacher just wants a hellish cludge of if statements - `if canada > usa && canada < norway && ...`

Comment: Yeah sounds like that.

Comment: Tell us more about "income"

Comment: Income is the input

Comment: @BobbyJackson Please show how "income" is assigned and used in your code

Comment: All code down below :)

Answer (score 1):

Python has a native function called min that can do the computation for you.
But if you're requested to do it manually, you can start with one of the taxes (let's say Canada's) and replace your variable with other values that you find are smaller:

(by the way, you should not name a variable `min`)

```
minTax = canada
if minTax > norway_tax:
    minTax = norway_tax
if minTax > USA_tax:
    minTax = USA_tax
if minTax > denmark_tax:
    minTax = denmark_tax
    

if minTax == canada :
   print('Canada')

if minTax == denmark_tax :
   print('Denmark')

if minTax == norway_tax :
   print('Norway')

if minTax == USA_tax :
   print('USA')
```

Using the min function would avoid the first set of ifs:

```
minTax = min(canada, norway_tax, USA_tax, denmark_tax)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this before but thought is was a to much mess:

```
#   Print lowest tax
     if canada <= norway_tax and canada <= USA_tax and canada <= denmark_tax:
        print(f'Lowest tax: {canada}')
        print('Canada')
     if norway_tax <= canada and norway_tax <= USA_tax and norway_tax <= denmark_tax:
        print(f'Lowest tax: {norway_tax}')
        print('Norway')
     if USA_tax <= canada and USA_tax <= norway_tax and USA_tax <= denmark_tax:
        print(f'Lowest tax: {USA_tax}')
        print('USA')
     if denmark_tax <= canada and denmark_tax <= norway_tax and denmark_tax <= USA_tax:
        print(f'Lowest tax: {denmark_tax}')
        print('Denmark')
```

It works but not if countries have the same lowest tax, what could I do to make that work, should be like this:

```
Income: 1000000
Lowest tax: 150000.0
USA
Income: 6000
Lowest tax: 1500.0
Denmark Norway USA
Income: -1
```

Here is all my code:

```
continue_input = True
income = 0

while continue_input and income >= 0:
    income = int(input('Income: '))

    if income >= 0:
    

    # Canada   
     canada_tax = 0.26
     canada = canada_tax * income

    # Norway
     if income > 3000:
        norway_tax1 = 0.1 * 3000
        tax_left = income - 3000
        norway_tax2 = 0.4 * tax_left
        norway_tax = norway_tax1 + norway_tax2
     elif income < 3000:
        norway_tax = 0.1 * income

    # Denmark
     denmark_tax = 0
     percent = 0
     for _ in range(int(income/1000)):
        denmark_tax += percent * 1000
        percent += 0.1
     denmark_tax += percent * (income%1000)

    # USA
     if income <= 1500:
        USA_tax = 0.12 * income
     elif income > 1500 and income <= 6000:
        USA_tax = 0.25 * income
     elif income > 6000 and income <= 10000:
        USA_tax = 0.38 * income
     elif income > 10000:
        USA_tax = 0.15 * income



#   Print lowest tax
     if canada <= norway_tax and canada <= USA_tax and canada <= denmark_tax:
        print(f'Lowest tax: {canada}')
        print('Canada')
     if norway_tax <= canada and norway_tax <= USA_tax and norway_tax <= denmark_tax:
        print(f'Lowest tax: {norway_tax}')
        print('Norway')
     if USA_tax <= canada and USA_tax <= norway_tax and USA_tax <= denmark_tax:
        print(f'Lowest tax: {USA_tax}')
        print('USA')
     if denmark_tax <= canada and denmark_tax <= norway_tax and denmark_tax <= USA_tax:
        print(f'Lowest tax: {denmark_tax}')
        print('Denmark')

# Print lowest if countries have the same lowest tax in alphabetic row.
```

Comment: @Pingu here is the full code